# Vue JS Is there a way to hide source code in the dist js file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, obs

I want to make a in-depth logging page, but the page will expose the type of logging I am doing, but I don't want the users to be able to open up the minified vue JS script and be able to read what is being logged. do some access control stuff for vue js? (I don't mean using v-if, people can still read the source of the vuejs dist file and see the logging)

Comment: unfortunately it will be complicated.
People with a bit of will and hack can easily access it.

Try to use a SPA rather than an SSR if you don't need SEO, something that surprises me a lot in the case of your application

Answer (score 1):

No anything that is sent to the client can be read. You can try to obfuscate the code with a mangler but a determined person will always be able reverse engineer it. Also there is no way you can hide sending the data back to the server.